# how to make Docker-compose run all services when debuging with Pycharm?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, pycharm

I have a simple dockerized Django gunicorn, nginx, and postgress project (each is a service).

When I run it with docker-compose up, everything works:

```
maximd@ubuntu ~/PycharmProjects/MyQ (master) $ docker-compose ps

     Name                    Command               State          Ports        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myq_database1_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp            
myq_djangoapp_1   /bin/sh -c gunicorn --bind ...   Up      8000/tcp            
myq_nginx_1       nginx -g daemon off;             Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

However, when I lunch it using the pycharm debuger it doesn't run nginx.

I suspect that since the djangoapp depends on the database service in my docker-compose.yml file it just creates them both, but it doesn't run nginx.

Here is what I see after I run it with the pycharm the debuger:

```
maximd@ubuntu ~/PycharmProjects/MyQ (master) $ docker-compose ps
     Name                    Command               State                  Ports               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myq_database1_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up       5432/tcp                          
myq_djangoapp_1   python -u /opt/.pycharm_he ...   Up       0.0.0.0:55488->55488/tcp, 8000/tcp
myq_nginx_1       nginx -g daemon off;             Exit 0
```

So, my question is this: is there a way to make nginx be a dependency of djangoapp also? is there a way to make pycharm run all services and not only the one I'm trying to debug?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/services/djangoapp
      - static_volume:/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/services/djangoapp/media
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database1_network
    depends_on:
      - database1

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/services/djangoapp/media
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  database1:  # <-- IMPORTANT: same name as in DATABASES setting, otherwise Django won't find the database!
    image: postgres:10
    env_file:
      - config/db/database1_env
    networks:
      - database1_network
    volumes:
      - database1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database1_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database1_volume:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Here is my debug configuration and interpreter configuration in the pictures.[image: remote interpreter]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to leave the `Service` part **blank** in the configuration?

Comment: @pawamoy, actually when I think about it, then no, I will try it today after work.

Comment: I have tried a few other things that may be relevant: 
In debug configuration: single instance only checkbox, checked and unchecked, both didn't do anything.

In debug configuration: setting the working directory to be:
/services/djangoapp (the projects root in the docker container) also didn't do anything

Comment: I really think that leaving Service blank will solve your issue. If you specify the `djangoapp` service, the nginx container is not started. But actually it might not be a problem because in local/development/debug you don't need nginx: gunicorn is enough. Maybe try to bind `- ports: 8000:8000` for the djangoapp service in your docker-compose!

Comment: @pawamoy I have tried your suggestion yesterday, pycharm doesn't allow to leave the service blank because it's trying to locate python interpreter inside the service.

Comment: Actually PyCharm allows it. What version do you have? I have the Professional one. Leaving services blank in a docker-compose configuration is possible, and then PyCharm runs `docker-compose -f compose_file.yml up -d`. It would have solved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it, what fixed it was to change docker-compose.yml to this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  djangoapp:
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/services/djangoapp
      - static_volume:/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/services/djangoapp/media
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database1_network
    depends_on:
      - database1
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/services/djangoapp/media
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  database1:  # <-- IMPORTANT: same name as in DATABASES setting, otherwise Django won't find the database!
    image: postgres:10
    env_file:
      - config/db/database1_env
    networks:
      - database1_network
    volumes:
      - database1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database1_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database1_volume:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Basically making djangoapp depend on nginx, and add restart: always to nginx and djangoapp.

Also in the Run/Debug Configurations window:

Host is: 0.0.0.0

Working directory: /services/djangoapp (like the one inside the djangoapp)

Path mappings: /home/maximd/PycharmProjects/MyQ=/services/djangoapp

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your nginx container is going down on it's own, just check `docker logs myq_nginx_1`

Comment: docker logs myq_nginx_1 returned some logs, but the times indicate that the logs are all from the docker-compose up command, there were None with relevant times for the django debuger runs